# Network interface will not come up, obtain a DHCP lease automatically

Tags: networking, 18.04, ethernet

I have a minimal Ubuntu 18.04 system. I want one of my network interfaces, `eth1`, to come up automatically at boot and obtain an IP address from DHCP.

I created `/etc/network/interfaces.d/default` containing:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

Hoever `eth1` is *not* brought up at boot time. Instead:

```
eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
```

I can run `sudo dhclient eth1` and it comes up and obtains an IP. But why doesn't this happen automatically?

Comment: Ubuntu Bionic: Netplan(Netplan replaced ifupdown as the default configuration utility starting with Ubuntu 17.10 Artful) https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-bionic-netplan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a comment in `/etc/network/interfaces` the default is to use [netplan.io](https://netplan.io) instead. The files in `interfaces.d/` were not being sourced.

```yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth1:
      dhcp4: true
```